# Could not establish connection to "hostname": The VS Code Server failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I looked at the similar questions to mine, and none of them seemed to fix my problem.
It returns a prompt that says `Could not establish connection to "hostname": The VS Code Server failed to start.` When I use the command `ssh pi@raspberrypi` and type in my password everything seems to work.

My Computer: Windows 11

Remote Computer: Raspbian OS

The `server.sh` file seems to be broken, but I don't know what the file should look like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#

case "$1" in
    --inspect*) INSPECT="$1"; shift;;
esac

ROOT="$(dirname "$0")"

"$ROOT/node" ${INSPECT:-} "$ROOT/out/server-main.js" --compatibility=1.63 "$@"
```

and this is the log file on the remote computer:

```
/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/bin/code-server: 12: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/bin/code-server: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/node: not found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### solution ：Kill VS code Server on host and reconnect maybe work

- show Command Palette : ctrl + shift +p
- input keyword : Remote-SSH
- select target : Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host...
- reconnect target serer will work

Answer (score 2):

### Another solution: Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host work

You can find `Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host...` via the command palette (ctrl/cmd + shift + p).

[image: Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host]

And if you select or enter the host IP, the vscode installed on that server will be uninstalled.

[image]

Then, if you connect to the server again through vscode-ssh, vscode will work well.
After several attempts, I also succeeded in connecting this way.

Comment: tried this Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host... it didn't work. I have updated the extension to see if it fixes it but the error still remains. Like the OP normal SSH from the command line works. The issue for the VSCode SSH extension repository on Github has been closed but the issue still persists. The connection works for one of my raspberry pi 4, doesn't work on the other I tried transferring the .vscode-server folder to the one not connecting but that didn't work.  I wonder how many are still struggling with this after over a year.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the suggested ways work, try downgrading to this version of vsc:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85

this was the only way i could make it work again.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Has same issues, after upgrading to latest v1_86, tried everything I could find in stackoverflow, nothing worked.

I am using latest macOS (Sonoma) on an Intel-based macbook pro 16 (2019) and remote the server is ubuntu 22.04.

Looking at the log it seems that the connection is established successfully but then something fails.

Had to downgrade to previous version (1_85), as also @chrischma suggested. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you tried above solutions, you can try this...

Possible Rootcause:

- Tar package is not installed on remote machine, which is used unpack downloaded files at remote machine

Conditions:

- VS Code remote via SSH
- passed on password prompt twice, then the error like this occurs: "vscode remote could not establish connection"
- Check the remote machine if there's existing ".vscode" file at /home directory (if not, chances are it fails at SSH)
- Verdict: SSH is definitely working based on logs & it stores data at remote machine

Solution:

- Install tar package at remote machine